# How to disable an AngularJs filter when checkboxes are false (disabled)?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a question about how to disable a AngularJS filter related to checkboxes.

I have a classic construction:

The object:

```
 $scope.wines = [
    { "name": "Wine a", "type": "red", "country": "france", "style": "strong" },
    { "name": "Wine a", "type": "white", "country": "italie", "style": "medium" },
    { "name": "Wine a", "type": "white", "country": "france", "style": "light" },
    { "name": "Wine a", "type": "rose", "country": "usa", "style": "strong" },
    { "name": "Wine a", "type": "champagne", "country": "chili", "style": "medium" },
    { "name": "Wine a", "type": "red", "country": "brazil", "style": "strong" },
    { "name": "Wine a", "type": "red", "country": "france", "style": "strong" }
  ];
  $scope.winetypes = {red : true,white : true,rose : true, champagne : true};
```

This filter is used to display only the related choice made with the checkboxes:

```
app.filter('winetypefilter', function () {
  return function(input, filter) {
    var result = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function (wine) {
        angular.forEach(filter, function (isfiltered, type) {
            if (isfiltered && type === wine.type) {
                result.push(wine);
            }
        });
    });
    return result;
  };
```

The results are displayed with this html code:

```
<li ng-repeat="(type, value) in winetypes">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="winetypes[type]" /> {{type}}
</li>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="wine in wines | winetypefilter:winetypes">
    {{wine.name}} is a {{wine.type}} with {{wine.style}} style from {{wine.country}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

- I would, when all the wines check-boxes are unchecked (false), to **disable** the **winetypefilter**, to display all the results on the page. I tried without success!!

Here the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nIQ2lkiJJY9MwJKHrqOk?p=preview

Comment: basically you want all items to be displayed when all checkboxes are unchecked?

Comment: yes, right!! nice help, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually tweak your custom filter, `winetypefilter`, to check if all `winetypes` boolean values are disabled. if all values are disabled, then simply return the original array, in this case `input`, otherwise continue with your original filter.

Note: I also changed the way you filtered the winetypes, the extra layer of `forEach` wasn't necessary to determine if filtering should take place. just check if `wine.type` of filter was true in the `winetypes` json

[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CjGvbO4aGgJYTfC0EIBp?p=preview)

e.g.

```
app.filter('winetypefilter', function () {
  return function(input, filter) {
    var result;

    if(canFilter(filter)) {
      result = [];
      angular.forEach(input, function(wine) {
        if(filter[wine.type])
          result.push(wine);
      });
    } else
      result = input;

    return result;
  };

  function canFilter(filter) {
    var hasFilter = false;
    angular.forEach(filter, function(isFiltered) {
      hasFilter = hasFilter || isFiltered;
    });
    return hasFilter;
  }
});
```

Comment: Similar but with a few less lines (for better or worse): http://plnkr.co/edit/BdGIFNFN1xOcvSBtLwlt?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.... I'm a newbie to AngularJS, your code helps me a lot!! Regards

Answer (score 1):

I used `ng-if` to show depending on whether all the checkboxes are checked...

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-if="check()" ng-repeat="wine in wines | winetypefilter:winetypes">
        {{wine.name}} is a {{wine.type}} with {{wine.style}} style from {{wine.country}}
      </li>
      <li ng-if="!check()" ng-repeat="wine in wines ">
        {{wine.name}} is a {{wine.type}} with {{wine.style}} style from {{wine.country}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

and the controller code..

```
  $scope.check=function()
  {
    if($scope.winetypes.red===false&&$scope.winetypes.white===false&&$scope.winetypes.rose===false&&$scope.winetypes.champagne===false)
    {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/MWL727Yfq8MLWodmaBDk?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.... I'm a newbie to AngularJS, nice because many solution are here... Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/w4aCjOW5UnnFQcAKYBT9?p=preview

```
app.filter('winetypefilter', function () {
  return function(input, filter) {
    var result = [];
    var alt = [];
    var flag = false;
    angular.forEach(input, function (wine) {
        flag = false;
        angular.forEach(filter, function (isfiltered, type) {
            if (isfiltered && type === wine.type) {
                result.push(wine);
                flag = true;
            }
        });
        if(!flag)
          alt.push(wine);
    });
    if(!angular.equals(result.length,0))
      return result;
    else
      return alt;
  };
});
```

As per one of the other comments, you can forgo the extra `forEach` 
Updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/w4aCjOW5UnnFQcAKYBT9?p=preview

```
app.filter('winetypefilter', function () {
  return function(input, filter) {
    var result = [];
    var alt = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function (wine) {
        if(filter[wine.type])
          result.push(wine);
        else
          alt.push(wine);
    });
    if(!angular.equals(result.length,0))
      return result;
    else
      return alt;
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.... I'm a newbie to AngularJS, your code helps me a lot!! I will analyse it com calm!! Regards

Comment: The latter code example reduced the code to one `forEach` with no extra function call as in @ryeballar's, but the trade off is the extra memory for the alternate array.  Credit to @ryeballar for figuring out that the extra `forEach` was unwarranted.

Comment: Nice, i was thinking about the memory, especially when the json file will grow up and grow up. Thanks !!